# Error 0 (non-NA) cases in writing function for regression

Tags: r, function, regression, linear-regression

I have a data which is like this:

```
full_data <- data.frame( STIRLING=rnorm(100,100,1),
    MEANWEXP=rnorm(100,100,1),
    IDRTOTALJOURNALS=rnorm(100,5,1) )
```

I want to write a function that gets response and predictor variables as an input, but is conditional on one of the predictors. I have written the following code:

```
regression=function(response,predict)
{
  if(predict==IDRTOTALJOURNALS)
  {
    full_data=data.frame(response,predict)
    full_data1=subset(full_data,full_data$IDRTOTALJOURNALS>5)
    model=lm(response~predict,data=full_data1)
  }
  else 
  {
      full_data=data.frame(response,predict)
      model=lm(response~predict,data=full_data)
  }
return(summary(model))
}
regression(STIRLING,MEANWEXP)
regression(STIRLING,IDRTOTALJOURNALS)
```

The first predictor variable(MEANEXP) works well, but the second one produces the following error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
In addition: Warning message:
In if (predict == IDRTOTALJOURNALS) { :
 
 Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

Comment: This is almost always wrong: `subset(full_data,full_data$IDRTOTALJOURNALS>5)`. Try instead: `subset(full_data, IDRTOTALJOURNALS>5)` The whole point of `subset` is to avoid having to repeat the dataframe name in the second argument. Sometimes subset will give you screwy results inside functions so it would be save to try: `full_data[ full_data$IDRTOTALJOURNALS>5 , ]`. And you cannot reference columns in the dataframe inside the function unless it has been defined outside the function (so I edited your question to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

It would need to be something like this:

```
regression=function(response,predict)
{
  if(predict=='IDRTOTALJOURNALS')
 
           #full_data=data.frame(response,predict)  not needed
     full_data1=subset(full_data,full_data$IDRTOTALJOURNALS>5)
     model=lm( paste(response,"~", predict), data=full_data1)
  }
  else 
  {
      #   full_data=data.frame(response,predict)  not needed
      model=lm( paste(response,"~", predict), data=full_data)
  }
return(summary(model))
}
regression('STIRLING','MEANWEXP')
regression('STIRLING','IDRTOTALJOURNALS')
```

Ther column names need to be passed as character values rather than symbol names and the formulas need to be built with pasting rather than expect the `~` function to interpret the values. The `formula` does not evaluate the symbols it finds, rather it tries to find existing data objects by those (unquoted) names. It can be very confusing if you are coming from a macro-style environment like SPSS or SAS where everything is "character".

Comment: The error is solved, however, the results are only shown for the full dataset with no filtering even when I use IDRTOTALJOURNALS as input.